# sql query, single table, one to many relationship; i need distinct values

Tags: helper

```
ColA  ColB

1   200    
1   10  
2   200   
2   10  
2   50  
3   200   
3   10  
3   50  
4   200   
4   10  
5   200
```

I need a query to give me `Col A` and `Col B`, with `Col B` having only 200 as the only value. 
I am trying everything. So basically i would get only:

```
Col A    ColB          
5        200
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking. Do you want to **count** (hint hint) the amount of times 200 appears in Col B?

Comment: why `5` in `Col A` in your desired result? why not `1/2/3/4` ?

Answer (score 0):

You question is not clear enough to give an answer that I would know is correct, however I will try my best.

You'll need to do the folllwing:

```
select distinct ColA, ColB from TableAB
where ColB = 200
```

Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

I have understood what you want to get. To make it easy, you should divide your query into 2 parts. First, count the number of **ColA** which have **500** as **ColB**. Then select the **count** of **ColA**, which does not repeat. (i.e, select the such **ColA** for which **count** is exactly = 1. (less than 2)).